# How can I do a God-tier url rewrite?

Tags: apache, web, url-rewriting

I'm using httpd on centos8, and I would like to put this rewrite into httpd.conf if possible!

I would like to make it so that a url like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/12345
```

gets rewritten as:

```
www.mydomain.com/folder/page.php?param=12345
```

I keep taking stabs at it and failing.  Can the good people of stackoverflow help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've found a solution but if anyone else has a similar requirement, it might be addressed with something like...

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName www.mydomain.com/12345
 Redirect 301 www.mydomain.com/folder/page.php?param=12345
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ultimately, it was solved by lines of gibberish in .htaccess: RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ $2/web/?go=$1 [R=301,L]